# what will happen if specified log file not found on getlogger("...") method in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

normally in file operations, if a specified file missing means it will throw file not found exception. Bu in my case

```
log.getLogger("someString");
```

didnt throw any exception even though there is no log file on the specified name in `getLogger()` method. Can anybody answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not specify the class of 'log', we can only guess here.

I know of no getLogger()-method in log4j that works on a file. The string used there has nothing to do with the name of the log file, it is the name of the logger. If no logger with the given name exists, a new one will be created and returned. A logger does not necessarily care if it has any attached appenders (which might or might not write to a file), so it doesn't care whether any files exist or not.

It is entirely possible and valid to create loggers that do nothing with log-statements.